# Count unique occurrences within a year

Tags: powerbi, dax

My database schema looks like down below

| ID | Date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | 2022/01/01 | Active |
| ID1 | 2022/02/01 | Active |
| ID1 | 2022/03/01 | Active |
| ID1 | 2022/04/01 | Terminated |
| ID2 | 2022/01/01 | Active |
| ID2 | 2022/02/01 | Terminated |

I'd like to calculate unique occurrences from start of selected date year, till the selected date. My formula is:

`CountOfUnique = CALCULATE( DISTINCTCOUNT( 'Table'[ID] ) , 'Table'[STATUS] = "Active",  DATESBETWEEN('CALENDAR'[DATE], STARTOFYEAR('CALENDAR'[DATE]), MAX('CALENDAR'[DATE]) ))`

In SQL I'd need something like

```
SELECT COUNT ( DISTINCT ID) FROM Table
WHERE STATUS = "ACTIVE"
AND DATE BETWEEN 2022/01/01 AND 2022/04/01
```

Comment: where do you store "the selected date" (which is 2022/04/01 in your sample) ?   is it a parameter or a slicer on the report ?

Comment: Slicer on the report made out of calendar field

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CountOfUnique =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[ID] ),
    'Table'[STATUS] = "Active",
    DATESBETWEEN (
        'CALENDAR'[DATE],
        STARTOFYEAR ( 'CALENDAR'[DATE] ),
        SELECTEDVALUE ( 'CALENDAR'[DATE] )
    )
)
```

Comment: Hey, 
It shows alike value as mine formula, when I slice by date, the MAX(DATE) is actually a SELECTEDVALUE date, right?
So I was kind of okay with my understanding?

Comment: You're right in your logic. MAX(DATE) is not a selected value date. SELECTEDVALUE() takes the selected value from the slicer and uses it. You can also define a default value if multiple values are selected in your slicer.

Comment: If multiple values are selected in your slicer, and you defined no default value, then SELECTEDVALUE() function gives error. Test and see it yourself.

Comment: Hi, 
I can see that the result is the same for both January and August, it looks like DATESBETWEEN doesn't work?

Comment: @lifeofthenoobie Are you sure ? DATESBETWEEN is the right function to use. SYNTAX: DATESBETWEEN ( <Dates>, <StartDate>, <EndDate> )

Comment: Put an ALL() function in front of ALL('CALENDAR'[DATE]) in the first argument of DATESBETWEEN; but I don't think ALL is needed.

Answer (score 0):

when you have a slicer on the visual, the start of selected date year doesnt mean much as you select the dates on the slicer. I created a `Calendar Table = CALENDARAUTO()` so it started from the 2022/01/01...

use one of these as you like...

[sample PBix File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1skyZwsyqsGuFEMPUWmQU-Q_HnRMV5fXS/view?usp=sharing)

```
Unique Count =
VAR _max =
    MAX ( 'Calendar Table'[Date] )
VAR _min =
    MIN ( 'Calendar Table'[Date] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[ID ] ),
        'Table'[Date ] <= _max
            && 'Table'[Date ] >= _min
    )
```

or only Active if you need

```
Unique Count (Active) =
VAR _max =
    MAX ( 'Calendar Table'[Date] )
VAR _min =
    MIN ( 'Calendar Table'[Date] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[ID ] ),
        'Table'[Date ] <= _max
            && 'Table'[Date ] >= _min
            && 'Table'[Status] = "Active"
    )
```

[image: date relationship]

[image: status]

Comment: Great Code.  but It is needed to have direct interaction with a slicer. You need to use SELECTEDVALUE() to bind it to slicer.

Comment: No need... It has a relationship with the Calendar Table 

Comment: OK, @Umut K. but You need to make it fail-safe. Good Luck, friend

Comment: Thanks @OzanSen but why do you think it may fail ? or in which condition it may fail ?

Comment: What If in reality in the table I got codes like 20220101 which represents JAN (I didn't want to upset anyone, because then calendar table is connected by integer column, not date field) ? Change MAX from date to integer field?

Comment: @Umut K When ALL() function has all the potential to make it invalid; because It removes filter context.

Comment: @lifeofthenoobie Then how do you plan to use DATESBETWEEN() and STARTOFYEAR () functions ? Your code is dead from the beginning. They work with date values. :)

Comment: Time Intelligence Functions need to have a date Table/field to work with. Integer columns are not enough to make them active. In that case, you need to be completely dependent on FILTER() function to constrain the rows to intended values.

Comment: Well, I got a calendar table with Dates, but just connection between calendar and fact table is made out of integers. I can refer to the date column, it doesn't have to be a key

Comment: that's because It is the part of date table, and you have a date column.

Comment: @OzanSen yes, but we do not use any ALL function here in this measure ))) think simple my friend )))

Comment: @lifeofthenoobie you'd better Transform this integer part into the date as it should be a date data...

Comment: @UmutK, It is just an example to invalidate your code. There is problem with your boundary. What do you think your min and max function will cover ?  the max and min date active in your filter context; but not the this year. By using STARTOFYEAR(), you ensure that the beginning of the year is selected as the min date. What about maxdate? The same problem again. However, If you used SELECTEDVALUE(), Then It would stop when It hit the selected value as max date. I hope I made it clear for you.

Comment: @OzanSen when you use a date slicer in the visual, you must use min & max. Otherwise it will not calculate right. Check my sample file with your answer inserted ;)